# gulp.js livereload with express server?

Tags: node.js, express, gulp, livereload

I am trying to setup my `gulpfile.js` to use livereload on an express server without much luck. I see examples out there but they seem to be related to a static file server.

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/gulp-as-a-development-web-server--cms-20903
http://rhumaric.com/2014/01/livereload-magic-gulp-style/

So I have an `app.js` file which does the standard express server with jade files, etc. What I want to do is get it to work with livereload from a gulp.js boot.

```
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
    var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    debug('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
});
```

There are lots of plugins like `gulp-livereload`, `connect-livereload`, `gulp-connect`, `gulp-watch` so how can I get this wired up?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node.js - Auto Refresh In Dev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35771931/node-js-auto-refresh-in-dev)

Answer (score 11):

I've added code that

1. Detects changes in server files and reloads the server via [nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon)
2. Waits for a couple seconds after process reload in order to give the server time to run its initialization code.
3. Triggers a change in a livereload server

**note 1** : Your build should also include a livereload server and attach livereload scripts to html files before calling the 'serve' task

**note 2**: This is an asynchronous task that never ends, **do not** use it as a dependency of other tasks

---

```
gulp.task('serve', function (cb) {
    nodemon({
        script  : <server start file>,
        watch   : <server files>
        //...add nodeArgs: ['--debug=5858'] to debug 
        //..or nodeArgs: ['--debug-brk=5858'] to debug at server start
    }).on('start', function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            livereload.changed();
        }, 2000); // wait for the server to finish loading before restarting the browsers
    });
});
```

Comment: it would be pretty helpful if the livereload part of this were included.  it looks like yours is probably the best solution here, but it's incomplete.

Comment: It might be helpful to note that if your calling `livereload.changed()` per doc spec, that does nothing.  https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-livereload#livereloadchangedpath  So you will need to add a string, or an object with a path there if doing it this way.  the answer from @andrei calls lr listen after, which probably also effectively reloads (the livereload portion).  

I have a code base using complicated watch and build examples on this, with alot of related gulp tasks https://github.com/brian-lamb-software-engineer/expressBuilder/tree/master/src/assets/js/gulp

Answer (score 4):

Here's my solution:

```
//gulpfile.js:
var gulp = require('gulp');
var nodemon = require('gulp-nodemon');
var server = require('gulp-express');
var lr = require('tiny-lr')();

gulp.task('default', function () {
    nodemon({
      script: 'server.js'
    })
    .on('restart', function () {
        console.log('restarted!')
    });

    lr.listen(35729);

    gulp.watch('server/**/*', function(event) {
      var fileName = require('path').relative('3000', event.path);
      lr.changed({
        body: {
          files: [fileName]
        }
      });
    });
});
```

You also need to include connect-livereload in your express server:

```
app.use(require('connect-livereload')());
```

Include it before bodyParser. I have read that this is not needed if you have the chrome live reload extension.

Answer (score 3):

[gulp-express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-express) is the right thing for you. It runs your express script as a server, with livereload!

Comment: gulp-express hs moved to gulp-live-server, and that itself has problems with the actual server file on require(), and needs the browser to reload as well. mixing nodemon with livereload, or gulp-live-server and watch seems a solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and was not able to find anything related. My solution ends up with the following piece of code in `Gulpfile`:

```
var fork = require('child_process').fork;
var tinyLr = require('tiny-lr');
var async = require('async');
var plugins = require('gulp-load-plugins')({ lazy: false });

var lr = null;
var lrPort = 35729;
var buildDir = 'build';
var serverAppFile = path.join(__dirname, 'build/server/app.js');

// This guy starts and stops nodejs process which runs our Express app
var app = {
    start: function(callback) {
        process.execArgv.push('--debug');
        var instance = app.instance = fork(serverAppFile, {
            silent: true
        });
        app.dataListener = function(data) {
            var message = '' + data;
            // Assume that server is started when it prints the following to stdout
            if (message.indexOf('Express server listening on port') === 0) {
                callback();
            }
        };
        instance.stdout.on('data', app.dataListener);
        instance.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
        instance.stderr.pipe(process.stderr);
    },

    stop: function(callback) {
        app.instance.stdout.removeListener('data', app.dataListener);
        plugins.util.log('Killing Express server with PID', app.instance.pid);
        app.instance.kill('SIGTERM');
        callback();
    }
};

// build-assets task actually processes my client js, less, images, etc and puts them to build dir
// build-server task copies server files (app.js, controllers, views) to build dir

gulp.task('serve', ['build-assets', 'build-server'], function(callback) {
    async.series([
        app.start,
        function(callback) {
            lr = tinyLr();
            lr.listen(lrPort, callback);
        }
    ], callback);
});

gulp.task('watch', ['serve'], function() {
    // Reload page if built files were updated
    gulp.watch([
        buildDir + '/**/*.handlebars',
        buildDir + '/**/*.html',
        buildDir + '/**/*.js',
        buildDir + '/**/*.css'
    ], function(event) {
        var fileName = path.relative(path.join(__dirname, buildDir), event.path);
        plugins.util.log('Detected updated file ' + fileName + ', reloading server and page in browser');
        async.series([
            // Restart Express server
            app.stop,
            app.start,

            // Send reload notification to browser
            function(callback) {
                lr.changed({
                    body: {
                        files: [fileName]
                    }
                });
                callback();
            }
        ]);
    });

    // Perform build steps on source file modifications
    gulp.watch(['app/**/*.js', '!app/**/*.spec.js'], ['build-app-js']);
    gulp.watch(['app/**/*.html'], ['build-templates']);
    gulp.watch(['app/**/*.less'], ['build-less']);
    gulp.watch(['server/**/*.*'], ['build-server']);
});
```

You'll need to install `tiny-lr`, `async`, `gulp-util` and `gulp-load-plugins` packages for this sample to work.
I guess that I'll create a separate Gulp plugin for it =)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [gulp-nodemon](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-nodemon) which will restart your server when code changes.

Example:

```
gulp.task('develop', function () {
  nodemon({ script: 'app.js', ext: 'html js' })
    .on('restart', function () {
      console.log('restarted!')
    })
})
```

Comment: For my express 4 app, once I changed `app.js` to `bin/www` I was golden. Thanks!

Comment: He is not asking for server restart. He's asking for *livereload*, which means to reload a browser on file change.

Comment: your half way there kwcto, then to combine nodemon with livereload solves both reloading the server, and the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Live reload should work with any nodejs script. Here is a good [gist](https://gist.github.com/hansent/9417349).

Comment: for the browser, not for the server though.  Ive had little luck getting it to trigger the server reload correctly, for requires() etc..

Answer (score 0):

To livereload both front and backend changes to the browser. There is also the option of not using Gulp. Then, the right combination of packages is 'livereload', 'connect-livereload', and a little help from 'nodemon'. Here's how they team up:

- `livereload` opens a high port and notifies the browser of changed public files
- `connect-livereload` monkey patches every served HTML page with a snippet that connects to this high port
- `nodemon` is then used to restart the server on changed backend files

**Set up livereload in Express**

You'll want to set up the Express to both start livereload server watching the public directory and ping the browser during nodemon-induced restart:

```
const livereload = require("livereload");
const connectLivereload = require("connect-livereload");

// open livereload high port and start to watch public directory for changes
const liveReloadServer = livereload.createServer();
liveReloadServer.watch(path.join(__dirname, 'public'));

// ping browser on Express boot, once browser has reconnected and handshaken
liveReloadServer.server.once("connection", () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    liveReloadServer.refresh("/");
  }, 100);
});

const app = express();

// monkey patch every served HTML so they know of changes
app.use(connectLivereload());
```

**Start Express with nodemon**

Then you'd start the server with nodemon, for example, with a dedicated watch script `npm run watch`.

The key point here is to ignore the public directory that's already being watched by livereload. You can also configure files with non-default extensions, like pug and mustache, to be watched.

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node ./bin/www",
  "watch": "nodemon --ext js,pug --ignore public"
},
```

You can read a longer explanation in ["Refresh front and backend changes to browser with Express, LiveReload and Nodemon."](https://bytearcher.com/articles/refresh-changes-browser-express-livereload-nodemon/)

Answer (score -1):

You can see the setup I used at http://github.com/arvsr1988/gulp-expressjs-setup