# Reload Express.js routes changes without manually restarting server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I tried `express-livereload`, but it just reloaded view files.

Should I use another tool, or this one can be configured to watch for my `index.js` file which runs the server?

I read that options are the same as `node-livereload`, and default for watched files include `.js` files.

Any URL you know with a simple configuration?

My main problem is how to setup good development environment for Express.js, and I would like to inspect the variables when I am making a request, is painful to restart each time I make a change in a route.

PS I tried `node-inspector` to inspect variables when server handles a request, but it seems `node-inspector` is not intended for that, right?

Comment: Have you tried using [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/)/[Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/)? I have found [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665993/gulp-js-livereload-with-express-server). You could do the same with grunt, but I prefer gulp as it has more understandable config.

Comment: I would prefer something configurable that works with default configuration.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node.js - Auto Refresh In Dev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35771931/node-js-auto-refresh-in-dev)

Answer (score 100, accepted):

I think [Nodemon](http://nodemon.io/) has what you're looking for.

> [Nodemon](http://nodemon.io/) is a utility that will monitor for any changes in your source and automatically restart your server. Perfect for development.

Example invocation:

```
nodemon index.js
```

Comment: Simple `npm install --save-dev nodemon` to add it to your package.json. Then you can add a script like this: `"dev": "nodemon index.js"`

Comment: But this restarts the server.

Comment: I love and use nodemon for a lot of static sites that I develop, but as Filipe says, your entire server process is stopped and restarted on change.  That's exactly the opposite of what the question asked for.

Comment: I think the essence of the question is a way for OP to make the development workflow easier i.e. not have to _manually_ restart the server (as indicated by the penultimate paragraph). OP also seems to be happy with the Nodemon (see first comment to answer).

But yeah, @zero298 and Filipe: you are both technically correct in that Nodemon restarts the server though :)

Answer (score 17):

I use express.js, normally start server by

```
npm start
```

with Nodemon installed, I use

```
nodemon --exec npm start
```

Note: `nodemon app.js` will NOT work here,

because express.js use `start` script

To install `nodemon`

```
npm install -g nodemon
```

Comment: Nodemon uses by default the start script in package.json, so instead of `nodemon --exec npm start` you can simply say `nodemon`.

Comment: But the entire server is restarting. will it keep my cpu  working for ever?

Answer (score 7):

You can livereload both front and backend changes to the browser using 'livereload', 'connect-livereload', and 'nodemon'. Also, this way you don't need Gulp or Grunt. Here's how they work together:

- `livereload` opens a high port and notifies the browser of any changed file
- `connect-livereload` monkey patches every served HTML page with a JavaScript snippet that connects to this high port
- `nodemon` restarts the server on any changed backend file

**Set up livereload in Express**

Set up Express to both start livereload server watching the public directory and ping the browser during `nodemon`-induced restart:

```
const livereload = require("livereload");
const connectLivereload = require("connect-livereload");

// open livereload high port and start to watch public directory for changes
const liveReloadServer = livereload.createServer();
liveReloadServer.watch(path.join(__dirname, 'public'));

// ping browser on Express boot, once browser has reconnected and handshaken
liveReloadServer.server.once("connection", () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    liveReloadServer.refresh("/");
  }, 100);
});

const app = express();

// monkey patch every served HTML so they know of changes
app.use(connectLivereload());
```

**Start Express with Nodemon**

Start the server with nodemon, for example, with a dedicated watch script by running `npm run watch`.

The key point here is to ignore the public directory that's already being watched by livereload. You can also configure files with non-default extensions, like pug and mustache, to be watched.

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node ./bin/www",
  "watch": "nodemon --ext js,pug --ignore public"
},
```

You can read a longer explanation in ["Refresh front and backend changes to browser with Express, LiveReload and Nodemon."](https://bytearcher.com/articles/refresh-changes-browser-express-livereload-nodemon/)

Answer (score 3):

It might interest you to know that since the release of Node.js V18.11.0, Node.js can automatically restart a server upon making a change to the `index.js` file.

To use the feature, run the server with the following command:

```
 node --watch index.js
```

**Note**: At the time of writing, the feature is still experimental.

Comment: Brilliant! Works out of the box on v18.15.0 with no additional flags. Prints an "experimental feature" warning, but is working perfectly.